# VB.net: INSERT INTO query generating all "-1" in Access Database

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, sql-insert

I have the following code and query:

```
Dim sqlCom As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO clasificador (codigo, deudor, oportunidad, banca, ejecutivo, garantia, ciiu, ras, actividad, fecha, analista, estatus, concepto, ult_act, ingresos, tipo, cumplimiento, multa_pot, roa2, ie2, ant, act, covenants, faltas, oportunidades, costos, pmaa, potencial) VALUES (codigo=@codigo, deudor=@deudor, oportunidad=@oportunidad, banca=@banca, ejecutivo=@ejecutivo, garantia=@garantia, ciiu=@ciiu, ras=@ras, actividad=@actividad, fecha=@fecha, analista=@analista, estatus=@estatus, concepto=@concepto, ult_act=@ult_act, ingresos=@ingresos, tipo=@tipo, cumplimiento=@cumplimiento, multa_pot=@multa_pot, roa2=@roa2, ie2=@ie2, ant=@ant, act=@act, covenants=@covenants, faltas=@faltas, oportunidades=@oportunidades, costos=@costos, pmaa=@pmaa, potencial=@potencial)", conn)
        sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codigo", txtCodigo.Text)
        sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@deudor", txtDeudor.Text)
        sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oportunidad", txtOportunidad.Text)
        sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@banca", drpBanca.Text)
        sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ejecutivo", txtEjecutivo.Text)
        sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@garantia", drpGarantia.Text)
        sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ciiu", txtCIIU.Text)
        sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ras", txtRAS.Text)
        sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@actividad", txtActividad.Text)
        sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha", dteFecha.Text)
        sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@analista", txtAnalista.Text)
        sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@estatus", drpEstatus.Text)
        sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@concepto", drpConcepto.Text)
        sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ult_act", dteUltAct.Text)
        sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ingresos", txtIngresos.Text)
        sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipo", txtTipo.Text)
        sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cumplimiento", drpCumplimiento.Text)
        sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@multa_pot", txtMultaPot.Text)
        sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@roa2", txtROA2.Text)
        sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ie2", txtIE2.Text)
        sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ant", txtAnt.Text)
        sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@act", txtAct.Text)
        sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@covenants", txtCovenants.Text)
        sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@faltas", drpFaltas.Text)
        sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oportunidades", txtOportunidades.Text)
        sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@costos", txtCostos.Text)
        sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pmaa", txtPMAA.Text)
        sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@potencial", txtPotencial.Text)
        Try
            'MsgBox("GO!")
            Select Case MsgBox("¿Seguro que desea crear?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Confirmar")
                Case MsgBoxResult.Yes
                    sqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    MsgBox("¡Listo!")
                    Me.Show()
                Case MsgBoxResult.No
            End Select
            'MsgBox("DONE!")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
```

I get no errors of any kind and everything works fine, but the information being inserted into the database is all "-1" (w/o quotes) in all fields (except date fields which have "12/29/1899"). I've gone through maybe 20 questions in Stackoverflow but they're all general syntax or spelling errors.

Any ideas?

Comment: 1. You are adding all your parameters as strings (varchar). I do not speak ?spanish? (I think thats what you have there) but maybe its not all string data types in your schema. As such you should probably convert the inputs `.Text` to the appropriate type like int or DateTime before assigning it with the `AddWithValue`. 2) You are using UPDATE syntax, insert syntax lists columns and then the values there after.

Comment: `they're all general syntax or spelling errors` but look at the code being used - are they doing what your code does?  Very likely not.

Comment: Why would someone vote down a question just because of rookie mistakes? I think it's a legitimate question which had no precedent in the site... #my2ct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every single one of these is WRONG:

```
INSERT ...  VALUES (codigo=@codigo, deudor=@deudor
                       ^^^^^^^^
```

You're not inserting your values, you're insert the result of a bunch of equality tests. You're inserting a record, so there's NOTHING to test for equality against, and all the tests fail, hence your -1.

Insert syntax is

```
INSERT INTO sometable (field1, field2, ...) VALUES (value1, value2, ...)
```

so you should have JUST this:

```
INSERT ... VALUES (@codigo, @deudor, etc....)
```

Comment: Thanks @MarcB, it worked like a charm! Sorry for my noobness :(